# sqlany_django doesn't save model to database

Tags: python, django, sybase

I'm connecting my django app to a sybase database using sqlany_django.

settings.py

```
'sybase': {
            'NAME': 'online',
            'ENGINE': 'sqlany_django',
            'HOST': 'srvsybase01.mydomain.com:6001',
            'USER': 'dba',
            'PASSWORD': 'test',
        }
```

When I try to commit an update to a model, obtained by an inspectdb, I cannot find persisted data in my sybase table.

```
try:
    Shop.objects.get(sitedomain=domain)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    shop = Shop.objects.get(cod_cli=cod_client, disable=0)
    shop.sitedomain = str(domain)
    shop.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my fork which force autocommit = True behaviour.

https://github.com/faxioman/sqlany-django

Comment: Great faxioman. Your fork saved me a lot of search and work. Have you thought to push your solution to SAP guys?

Comment: Glad to hear it :) Ok, I'll do a merge request.